# Is it "unsafe" to rely only on placeholders (input fields)?

Tags: usability, accessibility, input-fields

I've noticed that in many sites, the text within input fields are always either `label` tags and `span` tags. Twitter's example:

[image]

[image]

(in this case, the `labels` seem to be inside the input field).

I never see input fields without labels and with only the `placeholder` attribute.

Is it "unsafe" to rely only on placeholders?

Comment: Note that out of view of your cropped image, twitter has given a title to the fields which is the same as the placeholder text, so in this case all browsers should also show that as a tooltip at least during, or after edit, and usually before.

Comment: @RogerAttrill I'm not sure touch devices' browsers will show the tooltip.

Comment: @DA01 Well in this case of twitter, touch devices don't use placeholders.

Comment: There was a recent [useful article on UXMatters.com](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2013/02/dont-put-labels-inside-text-boxes-unless-youre-luke-w.php) about this very issue (including how Twitter use inline labels)

Comment: @RogerAttrill I guess I'm getting confused now. the `title` attribute is what the browser turns into a tooltip. Touch devices can use the `placeholder` attribute (iOS supports it, for instance).

Comment: @DA01 Sorry for confusion. Trying to be specific: twitter sign up on mobile devices doesn't rely on placeholders and does not use the placeholder in the same way - it puts in an example name (Larry Bird) and shows a standard Label to the left (including my iPad). On non-mobile devices, there is no label, but the title attribute gets used as a tooltip by the browser. I should note that I don't advocate reliance solely on placeholders. I was just making a point that perhaps twitter signup is a bad example for the OP in that it does not itself rely solely on placeholders (on mobile or otherwise)

Comment: Oh! Gotcha. I think the further confusion can come from the fact that 'placeholder' has been a generic UX term for quite a while now but now we also have a very specific 'placeholder' attribute in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For accessibility purposes, all form fields need a `label` to identify them. So that's part of the reason you see `label` tags used for this. The other reason is that `placeholder` attributes aren't necessarily widely supported yet (though we're close to it). All that said, a `placeholder` attribute and a `label` tag really serve two different purposes and it's important to understand that. A label identifies the field. A placeholder is more along the lines of 'help text'.

Answer (score 2):

Totally unsafe, as if a user makes an error, fills in incorrect data, he or she may have problem re-checking the whole form. In this case it is very simple. But even for login forms it is important. For example - in some systems (e.g. Pocket or Wunderlist on my iPhone) I keep filling in my email address as login and then being informed that the credentials are wrong. After a minute of fighting with the password, I start realizing that maybe the login is incorrect. But wait, the email address is ok! Takes me a while and needs deleting the whole email address for the label to reappear, telling me that I should use a login rather than email address.